# How to draw a dynamic tree using java?

Tags: java, graphics

I want to have some method which i give a tree to it, which it can have different child numbers, different node numbers and etc.
I want to have it in a good graphic shape and print the tree in a file.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this a couple of times for debugging purposes. Then I would simply create a `BufferedImage` and a few methods to draw lines and nodes using `setColor`. If your code is intended for performance, you should use a library or otherwise fancier methods to draw.

The trick to drawing trees is as follows:

- Have a method that computes the width of a subtree. In essence, this could just be a recursive method that sums the width of the children of the root, but with a minimum of 1 (for the root itself). Unless it's for debugging only, you should cache the width of each node, so the complexity of this goes down from quadratic to linear.
- Perform an Euclidean traversal, depth-first or breadth-first doesn't matter, but draw each node while leaving enough space for its siblings (using the width of the subtree of the parent node). For example, if the parent node has width 8 and the node you're drawing has width 5 (meaning most of the subtree's width is due to this node), the node should be drawn centered within 5/8ths of the subtree's width (so at 5/16th). Draw the node there and a line from the parent to the node.

Comment: thanks, but i am searching for a library which do this, like canviz which do this in JS language.